# How to call LabVIEW's .vi files in Mathematica?

Tags: packages, external-calls

I want to use Mathematica to process the data collected by LabVIEW, is there any way to implement Mathematica's call to LabVIEW's .vi files?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: ZiHao, you may be able to write your own import and export parser depending upon your knowledge of how those files are structured, but I recommend just exporting a different file format from LabVIEW that Mathematica already knows how to use.

Comment: `$ImportFormats`
gives a list of import formats currently supported in your Wolfram Language session.